# generating numpy arrays and naming them from a list of names

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops, dictionary

I want to generate some NumPy arrays with their names to be assigned to from a list of names. This is going to happen in a for-loop. The names are from a list. How can I do that?

For example, we have list = [ 'LA', 'SD', 'SB'], the eventually in a loop I want to have

LA = np.zeros([m,n])

loop 1
loop 2

```
LA = np.array(...)
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Yes: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: You don't - at least not with good Python style.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should use `exec` for that

```py
for name in list:
   exec(name + "= np.zeros([m, n])"
```